# Canvas that allows events for overlapped elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking for a way in WPF to recognize click events on all ZIndex levels. So this means I would like to recoginze a click also if another element (on the same canvas - only different ZIndex) is clicked.

What I want to achive with this functionality is that I have some ListBoxes on the same canvas and I would like to get the SelectionChanged event also when they overlap.

Edit: Added some code.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:type}">
    <ListBox SelectionMode="Extended" Background="Transparent"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Elements}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=DataContext}"
                                         MethodName="SelectionChanged" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="500" IsItemsHost="True"
                            Height="500"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent">
                    </Canvas >
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
  <DataTemplate>
```

In this example the SelectionChanged handler is only visible for one object (depending on ZIndex).

Comment: You want to get all UIElements under that clicked point?

Comment: Yes and I want that these elements react the same way as if they would have been clicked.

Comment: You can get the elements by using `VisualHitTesting` but i don't think you can pass the selection events down to another listBox.

Comment: It possbile to do this. Rohit and I need code to help you futhermore.